# How do i control when to stop the audio input?

Tags: python, django, speech-recognition

I am using the SpeechRecognition Python package to get the audio from the user.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
# obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)
```

This piece of code when executed starts listening for the audio input from the user. If the user does not speak for a while it automatically stops.

- I want to know how can we get to know that it has stopped listening to audio?
- How can I manually disable it ? I mean if i want to listen audio for 50 seconds and then stop listening to any further audio?

Comment: @NaveenKumar Nope

Answer (score 4):

1. as the documentation specifies, recording stops when you exit out of `with`. you may print something after `with` to know that the recording has been stopped.
2. here's how you can stop recording after 50 seconds.

```
import speech_recognition as sr 
recognizer = sr.Recognizer() 
mic = sr.Microphone(device_index=1) 
with mic as source:
    recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    captured_audio = recognizer.record(source=mic, duration=50)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to read the [library specifications](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst); then, you can check that using **record** method instead of **listen** method is preferable to your application.

Answer (score 1):

Late and not a direct answer, but to continuously record the microphone until the letter `q` is pressed, you can use:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from time import sleep
import keyboard # pip install keyboard

go = 1

def quit():
    global go
    print("q pressed, exiting...")
    go = 0

keyboard.on_press_key("q", lambda _:quit()) # press q to quit

r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone()
print(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names())

mic = sr.Microphone(device_index=1)


while go:
    try:
        sleep(0.01)
        with mic as source:
            audio = r.listen(source)
            print(r.recognize_google(audio))
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: on my macbook i need to us `sudo` to start this script, unless `keyboard` library bug it. `sudo python3 stack.py`